# Select by time range and segment results by 1 hour

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need help with the following requirement:

I have the following table:

```
id | status  | created_at             | closed_at
1     'OPEN'   '2019-05-08T12:30:24Z'   null
2     'CLOSED' '2019-05-08T12:50:22Z'   '2019-05-08T13:05:53Z'
3     'CLOSED' '2019-05-08T13:20:00Z'   '2019-05-08T13:40:12Z'
4     'CLOSED' '2019-05-08T13:55:47Z'   '2019-05-08T14:05:36Z'
5     'OPEN'   '2019-05-08T14:15:57Z'   null
6     'CLOSED' '2019-05-08T14:30:29Z'   '2019-05-08T14:40:00Z'
7     'CLOSED' '2019-05-08T14:55:38Z'   '2019-05-08T15:05:51Z'
```

For time range 
`created_at='2019-05-08T13:00:00Z'`
`closed_at ='2019-05-08T15:00:00Z'`
The output should be:

```
timestamp             |    id
2019-05-08 13:00:00      1,2,3,4
2019-05-08 14:00:00      1,4,5,6,7
```

Notice that `1` exists at 13:00 and at 14:00 because it's created_at starts at 12:30 and it doesn't have a closed_at (null) so it "lives" throughout the entire time range.

The closest I could come up with is the following:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE 'epoch' +
    INTERVAL '1 second' * round(extract('epoch' from created_at) / 3600) * 3600 as created_at,
    id
FROM issues 
WHERE (created_at BETWEEN '2019-05-08T13:00:00Z' AND '2019-05-08T15:00:00Z') OR 
    (closed_at BETWEEN '2019-05-08T13:00:00Z' AND '2019-05-08T15:00:00Z') OR
    (status='OPEN')
GROUP BY 
    created_at,id
ORDER BY created_at;
```

which gives

```
"2019-05-08 13:00:00+00"    "3"
"2019-05-08 13:00:00+00"    "2"
"2019-05-08 13:00:00+00"    "1"
"2019-05-08 14:00:00+00"    "4"
"2019-05-08 14:00:00+00"    "5"
"2019-05-08 15:00:00+00"    "6"
"2019-05-08 15:00:00+00"    "7"
```

Is that even possible to do from a select query?

Comment: And what are 3 and 4 counted in the first row?  And why would the times on the result set rows be different from the period specified?

Comment: 3 is created at closed at 13:00
4 appears at 13:00 and at 14:00 because it was created closed between those 2 hours.

Comment: You said: For time range  created_at='2019-05-08T14:00:00Z' .  Shouldn't that be 13:00:00Z?  The results would make a lot more sense in that case.

Comment: True, sorry for the typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you meant created_at = '2019-05-08T13:00:00Z', you should be able to do this pretty easily with tstzranges.

```
WITH time_ranges as 
   (SELECT tstzrange(t, t + '1 hour'::interval, '[]') as t_range 
    FROM generate_series('2019-05-08T13:00:00Z'::timestamptz, 
                         '2019-05-08T14:00:00Z'::timestamptz, 
                         '1 hour'::interval) g(t))
,
test_values AS (
  SELECT * from (values
  (1, '2019-05-08T12:30:24Z'::timestamptz, null::timestamptz),
  (2, '2019-05-08T12:50:22Z', '2019-05-08T13:05:53Z'),
  (3, '2019-05-08T13:20:00Z', '2019-05-08T13:40:12Z'),
  (4, '2019-05-08T13:55:47Z', '2019-05-08T14:05:36Z'), 
  (5, '2019-05-08T14:15:57Z', null), 
  (6, '2019-05-08T14:30:29Z', '2019-05-08T14:40:00Z'), 
  (7, '2019-05-08T14:55:38Z', '2019-05-08T15:05:51Z')
  ) v(id, created_at, closed_at)
)
select lower(t_range), string_agg(id::text, ',' ORDER BY id)
FROM time_ranges
JOIN test_values on tstzrange(created_at, closed_at, '[]') && t_range
GROUP BY lower(t_range);
         lower          | string_agg
------------------------+------------
 2019-05-08 13:00:00+00 | 1,2,3,4
 2019-05-08 14:00:00+00 | 1,4,5,6,7
(2 rows)
```

The only somewhat tricky part is joining on the overlap between the tstzrange from created_at to closed_at and the given hours.  You don't need the status column at all.

Comment: WOW!! it really works! you are doing it in a completely different way than I started doing - Thank you so much!

Comment: If I was giving it a 24h time range (instead of 13:00-14:00) and I don't need to return list of id's but just a `boolean` that is `true` if there is a entity in that 1 hour interval and `false` if there isn't - How would it this requirement change your code?

Comment: It might be better to ask a new question to get the full answer for that, but you would basically change the start time and end time in the generate_series command, left join on test_values instead of join, and instead of string_agg(id::text, ',' ORDER BY id) it would be something like: max(id) IS NOT NULL.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy - You're AWESOME!
I still need to figure out how you overcome the tricky part when `created_at` and `closed_at` can cover multiple 1h intervals.

Comment: can you please elaborate on the `g(t)` syntax.

Comment: g(t) is just an alias for the generate_series().  You could also put an AS in front of g(t), which may make it clearer.  I put it there so I could refer to the t column.  As for created_at and closed_at covering multiple intervals, all I'm doing is checking that tstzrange(created_at, closed_at, '[]') overlaps (the && operator) with t_range.